# Проблема при подключении к SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server, wcf

Здравствуйте! Не могу подключиться к экземпляру SQL Server 2012 Express из WCF-службы, хостом для которой является Windows-служба. Протоколы включены. Службы "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS2012)" и "Обозреватель SQL Server" работают. Брандмауэр отключён. База данных в норме. Установлена проверка подлинности Windows. Удалённые подключения разрешены.

Ошибка: "При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.)".

Фрагмент файла конфигурации приведён ниже:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSQLServer"/>   
    <add name="connection_1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=OIS-HP-308\SQLEXPRESS2012,1433; AttachDbFilename=g:\My projects\Cars_project_3\DB\Cars_DB_5\1\Cars_DB_5.mdf; Initial Catalog=Cars_DB_5; Persist Security Info=true;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Просьба помочь с решением данной проблемы.

Comment: Служба запускается на том же сервере, что и SQL Server?

Comment: Да, всё работает на одном компьютере.

Comment: А какие еще варианты пробовали? Например, вот так: "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS2012;AttachDbFilename=g:\My projects\Cars_project_3\DB\Cars_DB_5\1\Cars_DB_5.mdf;Database=Cars_DB_5;
Trusted_Connection=Yes"

Comment: Пробовал различные варианты. Уже разобрался с проблемой, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Привёл строку подключения к виду:

```
<add name="connection_1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=OIS-HP-308\SQLEXPRESS2012; Initial Catalog=Cars_DB_5; Persist Security Info=true; Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
```

Ещё важный момент: необходимо настроить в свойствах службы Windows параметры входа в систему, а именно учётную запись. Она должна быть с паролем, думаю, желательно с административными правами, и должна существовать с необходимыми разрешениями на экземпляре SQL Server.
Проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так. Добавьте данный раздел в App.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionName"
         connectionString="Data Source=MyPC\MYSQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Проблема решена.